# REST/Spring: get http-body info (plain/text) into variables/objects?

Tags: java, spring, rest, annotations

With the following code I managed to read http-post info that comes along as plain/text as a string and response to it with a string as well.

My problem is: I assume, that the http-body will contain info in form like:

```
Name="myName"&place="here"&age="40"
```

I receive this as a whole string, but am lost in finding a way to put those pairs into variables or an object. and also to put my respond into this schema
can you help?

```
@RequestMapping( value="/info", 
method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"text/plain"} )

public ResponseEntity<String> receiveBody(@RequestBody String vtext  )
{
    ....
    ....
    return new ResponseEntity<String> (vtext, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that much better solution for handling such problems is `@RequestParam` annotation. Let's assume that you have a form like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
 <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
 <input type="text" name="place" id="place"/>
```

All you have to do now is to put proper annotations in your method's arguments list. Example:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/info", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> receiveBody(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("place") String place, @RequestParam("age") int age)
{
    //you can do something with variables age, name and place here
    ....
    return new ResponseEntity<String> ("someResponse", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that is a great solution, that i may use for my second task.
But in this case, another party is setting up those data/info in the http-body  and sending them  along  (although I could get some influence, how), so I will not have the possibility to get info from a form

Comment: If another party is sending you key & value pairs it should be working anyway beacuse post variables are stored in the body in such format. If it doesn't work try to add `consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} `to the `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: thanks, your hint of regarding the content-type form mad the advice perfect.